# Retorno de email:null Laravel Socilite - Facebook/Github

Tags: laravel-5

Estou tentando realizar o cadastro/login de um sistema via *Facebook* usando o *Socialite* no *Laravel* 5, mas o problema é que o e-mail do usuário sempre retorna como `null`. Testei também com o *GitHub* e o retorno é `null`. Então, meu *app* no *facebook* está com permissão pra acessar o e-mail do usuário. Sei que o retorno do e-mail não é garantido, mas estou fazendo os testes com a minha conta e deixei meu e-mail como público para não ter erro, mesmo assim o retorno é `null`. Estou deixando passar algo, pois a principio é para ser simples, talvez visto por outros olhos ou com algumas dicas eu consigo resolver isso. Até por que não sou nenhum expert em *LARAVEL*.

Meu *FacebookController*

```
/**
 *
 */
public function login() {

    return \Socialize::with('facebook')->scopes(['email'])->redirect();

}

public function pageFacebook() {

    $user = \Socialize::with('facebook')->user();

    dd($user);
    return $user->getEmail();
}
```

Minhas rotas:

```
Route::get('loginFacebook', 'FacebookController@login');
Route::get('facebook', 'FacebookController@pageFacebook');
```

Meu retorno:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O dd para a execução do código. Isso estava lá antes?

Comment: Não, coloquei pra mostar como o User estava retornando;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estava trabalhando com isso também, tenta usar o código que estou usando, pois não consegui identificar o erro no teu:

```
namespace Laravel\Socialite\Two;

class FacebookProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * The base Facebook Graph URL.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $graphUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com';
/**
 * The Graph API version for the request.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $version = 'v2.5';

/**
 * The user fields being requested.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fields = ['name', 'email', 'gender', 'verified'];

/**
 * The scopes being requested.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $scopes = ['email'];

/**
 * Display the dialog in a popup view.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $popup = false;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getAuthUrl($state)
{
    return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase('https://www.facebook.com/'.$this->version.'/dialog/oauth', $state);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getTokenUrl()
{
    return $this->graphUrl.'/oauth/access_token';
}

/**
 * Get the access token for the given code.
 *
 * @param  string  $code
 * @return string
 */
public function getAccessToken($code)
{
    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get($this->getTokenUrl(), [
        'query' => $this->getTokenFields($code),
    ]);

    return $this->parseAccessToken($response->getBody());
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function parseAccessToken($body)
{
    parse_str($body);

    return $access_token;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getUserByToken($token)
{
    $appSecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $token, $this->clientSecret);

    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get($this->graphUrl.'/'.$this->version.'/me?access_token='.$token.'&appsecret_proof='.$appSecretProof.'&fields='.implode(',', $this->fields), [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    $avatarUrl = $this->graphUrl.'/'.$this->version.'/'.$user['id'].'/picture';

    return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => null, 'name' => isset($user['name']) ? $user['name'] : null,
        'email' => isset($user['email']) ? $user['email'] : null, 'avatar' => $avatarUrl.'?type=normal',
        'avatar_original' => $avatarUrl.'?width=1920',
    ]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getCodeFields($state = null)
{
    $fields = parent::getCodeFields($state);

    if ($this->popup) {
        $fields['display'] = 'popup';
    }

    return $fields;
}

/**
 * Set the user fields to request from Facebook.
 *
 * @param  array  $fields
 * @return $this
 */
public function fields(array $fields)
{
    $this->fields = $fields;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set the dialog to be displayed as a popup.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function asPopup()
{
    $this->popup = true;

    return $this;
}
  }
```

Comment: Deu certo, meu _FacebookProvider_ estava praticamente igual, pelo que vi a diferença significativa dos códigos é da função _getUserByToken_ . Eu não entendi muito bem, mas funcionou agora.

Comment: Opa! Blz então =D